# Why do I get SAXNotRecognizedException?

Tags: java, jaxb, unmarshalling

I want to read in an XML File and unmarshal it with JAXB.
But I always get the SAXNotRecognizedException.

I am running Java jdk 1.8.0_131.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    RecallRoot root = null;
    try {
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(RecallRoot.class);
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      unmarshaller.setSchema(marshal.createXsdSchema());
      InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("C:/Users/philipp/Desktop/test.xml");
      root = (RecallRoot)unmarshaller.unmarshal(inStream);

    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
      System.out.println(t);
    }

    root.getMake();
  }

  private static Schema createXsdSchema() throws SAXException {
    SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
    return factory.newSchema(marshal.class.getResource("recallFiles.xsd"));
  }
}

org.xml.sax.SAXNotRecognizedException: http://javax.xml.XMLConstants/feature/secure-processing
    at org.apache.xerces.framework.XMLParser.setFeature(XMLParser.java:1448)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.SAXParser.setFeature(SAXParser.java:578)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.setFeatures(SAXParserImpl.java:150)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.<init>(SAXParserImpl.java:133)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParserImpl(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:113)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl.setFeature(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.util.XmlFactory.createParserFactory(XmlFactory.java:121)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.getXMLReader(UnmarshallerImpl.java:139)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:276)
    at de.vw.hst.server.thread.recallFilesMarshallHelper.marshal.main(marshal.java:22)
```